# Codeigniter image manipulation class rotates image during resize

Tags: codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter's image manipulation library to re-size an uploaded image to three sizes, small, normal and large.

The re-sizing is working great. However, if I'm resizing a vertical image, the library is rotating the image so it's horizontal.

These are the config settings I have in place:

```
     $this->resize_config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
     $this->resize_config['source_image'] = $this->file_data['full_path'];
     $this->resize_config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;

     // These change based on the type (small, normal, large)
     $this->resize_config['new_image'] = './uploads/large/'.$this->new_file_name.'.jpg';
     $this->resize_config['width'] = 432;
     $this->resize_config['height'] = 288;
```

I'm not setting the master_dim property because the default it set to auto, which is what I want.

My assumption is that the library would take a vertical image, see that the height is greater than the width and translate the height/width config appropriately so the image remains vertical.

What is happening (apparently) is that the library is rotating the image when it is vertical and sizing it per the configuration.

This is the code in place I have to do the actual re-sizing:

```
        log_message('debug', 'attempting '.$size.' photo resize');
        $this->CI->load->library('image_lib');
        $this->CI->image_lib->initialize($this->resize_config);
        if ($this->CI->image_lib->resize())
        {
              $return_value = TRUE;
              log_message('debug', $size.' photo resize successful');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->errors[] = $this->CI->image_lib->display_errors();
            log_message('debug', $size.' photo resize failed');
        }
        $this->CI->image_lib->clear();
        return $return_value;
```

EDIT

I think the problem may be from the upload library. When I get the image_height and image_width back from the upload, the width seems to be larger even though I uploaded a vertical image.

This is a portion of the code I'm using to upload the photo:

```
     $this->upload_config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg';
     $this->upload_config['max_size']  = '2000';
     $this->upload_config['max_width']  = '0';
     $this->upload_config['max_height']  = '0';
     $this->upload_config['upload_path'] = './uploads/working/';


     $this->CI->load->library('upload', $this->upload_config);
     if ($this->CI->upload->do_upload($this->posted_file))
     {
         $this->file_data = $this->CI->upload->data();
         $return_value = TRUE;
         log_message('debug', 'upload successful');
     }
```

I added some logging to check the values:

```
     $this->is_vertical = $this->file_data['image_height'] > $this->file_data['image_width'];
     log_message('debug', 'image height:'.$this->file_data['image_height']);
     log_message('debug', 'image width:'.$this->file_data['image_width']);
     if ($this->is_vertical)
     {
         $this->resize_config['master_dim'] = 'height';
     }
     else
     {
         $this->resize_config['master_dim'] = 'width';
     }
    log_message('debug', 'master_dim setting:'.$this->resize_config['master_dim']);
```

These are the results of the log:

DEBUG - 2010-03-16 18:35:06 --> image height:1536
DEBUG - 2010-03-16 18:35:06 --> image width:2048
DEBUG - 2010-03-16 18:35:06 --> master_dim setting:width

Looking at the image in photoshop, these are the dimensions:

height: 2048
width: 1536

Anyone know what might be causing the upload library to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - I decided not to trust photoshop and opened the images I was testing in quicktime and safari. I discovered that they were actually still horizontal.

So Codeigniter was operating exactly as expected.

I went back into photoshop, did a save for web on the test images, re-uploaded them and it worked as expected.

I then stripped out the extra code that I had added to test whether the image was vertical and the library works as I expected it would.

Now - I need to figure out how to prevent end users from doing this exact thing.

Thanks for taking the time to answer my question musoNic80. Hopefully someone else can learn from my mistakes here.

Comment: Glad you've worked it out. Good look with figuring out the next bit!

Comment: Did you ever figure out a good way to protect end users from doing the same thing? I'm experiencing the exact same problem. Image looks right side up, but when you open it in safari, it's sideways.

Comment: I never did find a good way to do this, but to be honest, I haven't put much time into it.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used this library, but having read the documentation, I wonder whether the master_dim property might help. If you set this to 'height' for vertical images that might keep them the right way up. You could just parse each image through a conditional to see if the image is vertically aligned and then only set this property if need be.
My other thought is about the maintain_ratio property. The documentation says that with this set to 'TRUE' it will resize as close to the target values as possible whilst maintaining the aspect ratio. I wonder if it thinks that rotating the image allows it to preserve this ratio more accurately? As an experiment, try setting this value to 'FALSE' for vertical images.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll give this a shot tonight. Wouldn't you think though, that the library would handle setting the orientation properly by itself? 

The documentation makes it sound like it will.

Comment: See my edits above. I discovered that the upload class was bringing back inaccurate height and width information for the uploaded photo.